# CHROME-EXTENSIONS: How can I run my extension before clicking it when I change the url?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to do a chrome extension. In my extension, icons change when a condition change. I have popup.tsx and background.ts. In popup.tsx, I change my icon. In background.ts, I detect the url changes and if it changes, I want to run my popup script again.

In addition, when I reset my extension, it didnt start to work if I dont open its popup. How can I do these?

Here is my background script:

```
const dene = () => {
  console.log('dene works')
  return 'dene'
}

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener((activeInfo) => {
  console.log('listener works')
  chrome.scripting.executeScript(
    {
      target: { tabId: activeInfo.tabId },
      func: dene,
    },
    () => {
      chrome.runtime.lastError
    }
  )
})
```

Comment: The popup runs only when shown.

Comment: @wOxxOm but I want to change it realtime when I change the tab or url. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't see how it's related to the popup. Just do it in the background script.

Comment: @wOxxOm it also not working I am editing the code. My dene func not works

Comment: Start by investigating the errors in [devtools for the background script](/a/10258029). Your manifest.json may be missing `scripting` in `permissions` and `<all_urls>` in `host_permissions`.

Comment: @wOxxOm I checked but still not works

Comment: I can't help further without seeing the relevant sections of your manifest.json. Also note, that executeScript won't work on chrome:// pages or on the newtab page.

Comment: @wOxxOm do you want to see my manifest file? I you want I can add